# Is it possible to predefine the initial size of a Str?

Tags: raku

In some languages it is possible for the developer to specify an initial size for a string. Has Raku something similar? I have a string where I'll be concatenating text a few thousand times. The final size can be calculated before creating the string. I would like to test if I can save a few 100ms with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: when you concatenate strings in Rakudo on the MoarVM backend, you don't actually create a concatenated string: internally, you have an object that consists of the separate pieces of strings.

There is only one case where the string actually gets concatenated: and that's  when you use it as a haystack in a regular expression.  And I believe there's a maximum number of "pieces" of string that, when reached, will cause actual concatenation in memory.

If you're looking at optimization: then don't concatenate each time, but push to a native `str` array, and when done, then `.join` that:

```
my str @parts;
while $todo {
    @parts.push: "foo";
}
@parts.join
```

This is generally faster because a. you're using native strings, and b. all of the concatenation logic (which is actually not as simple as you think because e.g. a diacritic codepoint can be at the start of a part, and that needs to possibly be joined with the last codepoint of the previous part) can be done in the VM without needing to switch between HLL ops and C-code of the VM.

Comment: I have tried to do this in the past with a Str array + join and I didn't see any difference. The same happens with your native version. Maybe the bottleneck is somewhere else. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Not a `Str` array, but a `str` array!  The `Str` array is **NOT** native!

Comment: Some benchmark: `my str @a; @a.push(~$_) for ^1000000; @a.join` is about 3x as fast as `my Str @a; @a.push(~$_) for ^1000000; @a.join`

Comment: I know. That's why I said "The same thing happens with your native version" :) . Anyhow, it looks like my problem is not the concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

*To augment the excellent answer by @ElizabethMattijsen:*

It depend on what you mean by 'initial size'. If you're getting your string via `IO`, instead of using something like `lines` you can try the Raku function `readchars`, which takes a `$chars` delimiter defaulting to `65536`.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/readchars

Limiting the `readchars` string character length (`$chars`) might give you the speed-up you're looking for:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $fh = open $*IN; given $fh { say .readchars: 5; .close;}'  letters_one_per_line.txt
a
b
c
```

When you say 'concatenating' text, are these contiguous segments from a file? If so then `readchars` is your friend:

```
~$ raku -e 'my $fh = open $*IN; given $fh { $_.readchars( 5 ).print xx 2; .close;}' letters_one_per_line.txt
a
b
c
d
e
```

Additionally, Perl has a well-known `IO::String` module which is replicated in the Raku ecosystem by the identically-named Raku `IO::String` module. These modules purportedly make the problem you're addressing more tractable:

https://raku.land/github:hoelzro/IO::String

Unfortunately the Raku `IO::String` module hasn't been updated in a number of years. But maybe the OP's interest will stimulate further development!

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The text is coming from a hash, but it looks like the problem is not in the concatenation. (Just in case, I didn't down-vote your answer)